# Invalid registration token. Check the token format

Tags: android, firebase, android-push-notification

Invalid registration token. Check the token format. when sending push notification from firebase console in android

[image]

Comment: i think error itself is more precise. you have invalid FCM token try to regenerate.

Comment: I already regenerate FCM token.. but still this error occured....

Comment: can you post the token?

Comment: eDSeblLGdsw:APA91bEhGNgUJ_czIy9J2RLVB4EhqCRp-Sln8nFV221QxNuvvdcws90TRXz8N3HjuGFgjpEmXMGPg8x26MmcbPqy

Comment: try to send push notification with pushtry.com

Comment: Unauthorized
Error 401  occured when sending notification

Comment: First write some code to generate and log the token (if you haven't). Next, try uninstalling your app and reinstalling to trigger `FirebaseInstanceIdService` which will generate and log your device token. Third use that token to send PN from your console. Also make sure there are no leading and trailing white spaces in your instance id.

Comment: I have already added FirebaseInstanceIdService but sitill error occured

Answer (score 0):

By error "**invalid fcm token**" shows a link to this single page. I'll write the solution to my problem here, maybe it will help someone.

In my case, it was carelessness: in my project there were **two** files for test and prod **google-services.json**. When I was building the production version, I substituted the test google-services.json instead of google-services.json. Please note which google-services.json the application is built with.